# Solving the purple & white pillars

Tags: fez

I have encountered two kinds of pillars in the game: I've solved the vibrating type, but I'm having trouble solving the white or purple pillars (that have floating dots in their hollowed tops).

How do I solve these pillar puzzles?

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Nondescript isn't very...descriptive. Is it white or is it purple? Where are you, exactly?

Comment: They're in several places throughout the game—flat, rectangular pillars maybe two or three blocks high with a floating dot in the middle. Those who have played the game will understand from these details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Upon completing the game, you'll unlock New Game+, which transfers your stats and adds first-person view after the intro.

Near a purple or white pillar, go into first-person view and look for a string of white tetrominos (Tetris blocks). They can be converted to buttons with [the tetromino cipher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177).

If the white string is vertical, read it with your head tilted to the right. Then [convert the tetrominos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) and punch them in. The sequence should be about eight units long, and unique for each game. An anticube will appear above the pillar.

[image: Lighthouse pillar and tetromino string]
[image: Lighthouse pillar tetromino string]
[image: Lighthouse pillar anticube]
[image: Forest pillar and tetromino string]

**Here are the codes, if you're lazy:**

- Lighthouse purple pillar: **`↑ LT RT ↑ LT ↑ RT ↑`**
- Forest white pillar (first): **`→ RT ← LT ← ↑ ↓ A`**
- Forest purple pillar (second): **`LT A RT ↑ ↓ LT RT A`**
- Forest white pillar (third, near temple warp zone): **`← ← ↓ ↓ → → ↑ ↑`**

The [U-shaped tuning fork pillars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/what-do-we-do-with-the-u-pillars) work differently.

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful ! How did you find this ?

Comment: Lots of looking around