# What do we do with the U-shaped tuning fork pillars?

Tags: fez

The controller vibrates when I'm near them, but I don't know what to do.

Screenshot of one of them on the map:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The left and right motors in your controller will play a pattern when approaching these. It will pause briefly before repeating. You need to mime the pattern back with your left and right triggers.

My vibration was off, so I missed this the first time through. If you're having trouble, the right motor was a higher pitch in my case. Instead of feeling the sides, I listened for the pitch.

As far as I know, across ports, you can't solve this on your own without a vibrating controller.

[image: U-shaped pillar]
[image: anticube where U-shaped pillar used to be]

**Here are the codes, if you're lazy or without:**

- Waterfall neon pink/blue subroom tuning fork: **`LT RT RT RT LT RT RT LT`**
- Lighthouse tuning fork: **`LT RT RT LT LT LT RT RT RT RT`**
- Sewer tuning fork: **`LT LT LT RT LT RT LT RT`**
- Lava tuning fork: **`LT LT RT LT LT RT RT RT`**

Comment: Wow, vibration was off for me too so this one was ultra-confusing. Some of these solutions blow my mind....

Comment: Yeah, they could have been less oblique with the in game queue for this.  I also had vibration off.  Like several of the puzzles I couldn't solve I was pretty bent that the solution involved information I didn't have.

Comment: So how do you do these in the various desktop ports, when you're using the keyboard?  (Frustratingly, I managed to solve one by pure chance.)

Comment: How do you manage to do it if you are in a PC (without vibration controller)? Maybe there we should disable the vibration in the options in order to something to give us an alternative.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't solve this on your own without a vibrating controller. As I said in the answer, my vibration was off when I did this on the 360, and there was nothing to indicate the room's purpose without it.

Comment: I have tried listening to the pitch of the rumbling sound played on the speakers on a PC, and heard no correlation between the rumble sounds and which button you press. Each rumble sounds a little different, but the sounds are pretty much random – there’s no consistent difference between the `LT` and the `RT` rumble sounds.

Comment: At least there is a vague hint that there’s something missing on a PC. When you press Cancel/Talk in front of the tuning fork, sometimes, your companion Dot says “Woah! Can you feel that?” Not many PC gamers would take that as a reference to an Xbox controller’s vibration, though.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: YMMV, but my controller made two different audible pitches depending on the side vibrating. I recall the "Woah!" part on the 360, which didn't make me exactly think of my vibration turned off, but better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: @Sean When [I said](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/what-do-we-do-with-the-u-shaped-tuning-fork-pillars/62536?noredirect=1#comment180572_62536) that I heard no pattern in the rumbling sounds, I was talking about the pitches of sounds from computer speakers, not the pitches of vibration of a controller. The game plays faint rumbling sound effects through standard audio when you’re near a tuning fork.

Comment: There is definitely a way to do it on the PC ports; I've seen vague references to it having something to do with sound (maybe left/right speakers?) but haven't seen it made explicit.

Comment: I confirm the possibility to solve this without vibration. You have to listen to the sequence of noises which are being outputed to your left/right speaker while you are standing close to "U".  It's better to use headphones for that task.

Comment: I have several rumble controllers (Logitech, Saitek) for PC. Fez seems to recognize them as vibrating controllers, but unfortunately, no vibration. You still have to listen to the sequence of noises through your speaker or headphones.

Answer (score 9):

> If you're playing on the PC, while you're standing near the tuning fork a low tune will be will be played on the left or right earphone. Press the corresponding key (A or D) to rotate the perspective following the tune.

I checked with my headphones it's very subtle but it's there. So, I think with normal speakers you'll definitely not hear a thing ;-)

Source : http://uk.ign.com/wikis/fez/Tuning_Fork_Rooms