# the room down underneath the lighthouse

Tags: fez

In the room that appears under the bridge in the lighthouse area, that has appeared now that I have lowered all of the water, when I go I don't know how to uncover the secret.

Comment: If you are talking bout the room with the tuning fork, then related question - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/what-do-we-do-with-the-u-shaped-tuning-fork-pillars

Comment: The tuning fork room is the one accessed by lowering the water.  Confirmed here: http://www.ign.com/wikis/fez/Lighthouse_Door

Answer (score 3):

The comments above are valid. This tuning fork question can be answered  here: [What do we do with the U-shaped tuning fork pillars?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62533/what-do-we-do-with-the-u-shaped-tuning-fork-pillars)

Solving this puzzle lies in listening to the vibrations made on each side of the controller when you get close to the tuning fork.

> The explicit answer is: LT,  RT, RT,  LT, LT, LT,  RT, RT, RT, RT

Comment: you can also tell by stereo sound if you turn up the volume or use headphones. on ps4 i found it easier to tell this way. maybe the x360 controller has more distinct left/right vibration than the ps4 controller does.