# What is the secret of the Cube Statues in Fez?

Tags: fez

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I solve the pillar puzzles in Fez?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62428/how-can-i-solve-the-pillar-puzzles-in-fez)

What am I supposed to do with these statue/towers?

[image]

[image]